# how to join two collections in mongodb

Tags: mongodb

I have 2 collections userInfo and transationHistory. userInfo contains userId, registerDate, and etc., and transationHistory contains userId, transationId,itemId,etc.
databases look as follow, there are more than 1k data:

```
transationHistory:{
 {
   transationId:asd123
   itemId:A
   userId:123
 }

 userInfo:{
  userId:123
  registerDate:"06-18-2018"
 }
```

so I want to get users who bought item A with their registerDate.

```
db.transationHistory.aggregation({$match:{item:"A"}},{$project:{userId:1}})
```

then i get a list of userId, then

```
db.userInfo.aggregation({$match:{userId:{$in:[<listOfUserId>]}}},{$project:{registerDate:1}})
```

then I put both result sets into excel and use vlookup function to get the union. Is there an easier way just using mongodb query to get the union?

**EDITED:**

I know how to do this in mySQL, as follow:

```
SELECT T.itemId,T.userId,U.registerDate
FROM transationHistory T,userInfo U
WHERE T.userId=U.userId AND T.itemId="A"
```

sample output:

```
{
itemId:A  
userId:123  
registerDate:"06-18-2018"
}

{
itemId:A  
userId:1435  
registerDate:"06-16-2018"
}
```

Comment: Can show us a sample of data that you want at the end?

Comment: Yes there is. Look into [$lookup](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) pipeline of aggregation framework

Comment: JFYI, "union" means something else. What you want here is generally called "join".

Comment: @SergioTulentsev thanks for the FYI, i'm new to mongodb and English isnt my first language, what is "union" means in this situation?

Comment: @GeorgeBailey I looked into the $lookup, for this example is enough, but what if I want to perform greater than or less than? For example, userId in transationHistory less than userId in userInfo. In the page, it said "$lookup performs an equality match on the foreignField to the localField  "

Comment: @twjacky "userId is less than another userId" - can you come up with a legit usecase for this? Id field is a thing on which you just don't do range comparisons.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev i said  "userId is less than another userId"  since this is the only  variable in both db. I just want to know what should I do when I encounter range comparisons. I don't have a legit case in mind, I will ask that when I encounter that. Thanks for the help tho.

Comment: @twjacky: yes, come with a real case, then we'll see about that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use aggregate function with $lookup.

```
.aggregate([
        {
            $lookup: {
               from: "transationHistory",
               localField: "userId",
               foreignField: "userId",
               as: "result"
            }
        }, //other parts of aggregate
    //match, project, group or whatever you need 
])
```